# Understanding the folders and files generated by Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Short version of the question: What are `objects.mk`, `sources.mk`, `makefile`, `subdir.mk`, `*.o` and `*.d` files generated by Eclipse?

---

Long Version of the question:

1. In my home directory I have the `workspace` directory. Whenever I create a project and call it `ProjectName` a new directory (also called `ProjectName`) is created by Eclipse in the `workspace` folder.
2. In my project I create different classes, every class is associated with 2 files (source file `ClassName.cpp` and header file `ClassName.h`). These files are put into the `workspace/ProjectName/src` folder.
3. Now I `Build` my project in Eclipse and in the `workspace/ProjectName` a new folder appears. It is called `Debug`.
4. In this folder there is only one file whose functionality I understand: `ProjectName`. It is the executable. If I type its name in the command line, my program will be executed.
5. Another 3 files are unknown to me: `objects.mk`, `sources.mk`, `makefile`.
6. Moreover, in `Debug` folder there is `src` directory. It contains `subdir.mk` file whose meaning is unknown to me as well as `ClassName.o` and `ClassName.d` files (if I have N classes there will be N pairs of the `*.o` and `*.d` files.)

Can anybody, please, explain the meaning and purpose of these files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`objects.mk`, `sources.mk`, `makefile` and `subdir.mk` are makefiles generated by Eclipse according to your project type (executable, library, shared library). For their contents and how these work refer to the `make` command documenation of your toolchain. In short these are responsible to call the compiler and linker.

`ClassName.o` is the object file generated by the compiler, all of them will be linked together to an executable or stored in a library (depending on project type).

`ClassName.d` is a so called dependency reference file that is generated by the compiler (on demand) and included into the makefiles, that it's possible to track changes in header files, and recompile the concerned source files if neccessary.

Comment: As far as I understand the make file puts the object files together to get an executable. What is not clear to me is why do we have so many make files. Why one is not sufficient? Are they all used?

Comment: `makefile` is the main entry, it includes the `sources.mk`, `objects.mk` and `subdir.mk` makefiles. I didn't go to the details there, but I guess it's about better structuring and easier (automated) management of the build system. When setting up buildsystems for a project manually, we're usually doing the same.

Comment: Make is a specialized programming language designed with a focus on what gets turned into what else (.c -> .o -> executable, or any other dependencies for generated documentation etc).  You don't write anything but the simplest of programs in one source file.  The same goes for make; you use multiple files for modularity.